# P channel switch for external relay controll

Tags: mosfet, relay

This circuit is going to be in a production environment. I want to turn a relay on and off using a P-channel MOSFET. This action of turning on and off is not a periodic signal at a high frequency, hence a MOSFET driver is not needed.

**When the controller is set high (activated), it pulls the output to ground.**

R3 is added to limit the current into the gate. R2 is added to pull up the gate to 12V, so it is not floating. Diode added is a flyback diode.

The internal circuitry contains a 3V voltage that is pulled through R1.

Is this circuit sufficient for a production design? What standards do you guys follow when designing a similar circuit?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4mbea.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Also by the looks of it the IRF9530 FET will not work because the Vgs is to high, are my calculation coorect?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flay94.png)</sup>

Edit 1:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8euht.png)</sup>

Edit 2:

[image]

Edit 3:

A redundant pull-up is added so even if the control internal circuit is not plugged in, the load is still OFF.

[image]

Comment: Others have pointed out issues with your circuit. I would like to ask you why you want to use a  magnetic relay. Magnetic relays have a relatively high energy cost, and therefore, I would not suggest using one unless you _need_ to use one. So, what exactly is the load that the relay will be switching? Could a solid state device, such as a mosfet serve your purpose instead?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I have to use the Relay, no other option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the circuit is as shown it will not work at all, (or it will pull the 3V supply up to 12V).

There will be about 9V on the coil with switch open and about 11V on the coil with switch closed. The MOSFET will never turn off or on completely. Remember Vgs is what controls the MOSFET.

You should probably be using an N-channel MOSFET (or two MOSFETs) depending on what you are trying to do.

DC relays do not have an inrush current, so not sure where your numbers are coming from- they sound more like an AC relay specification. Powering an AC relay from the nominal AC voltage in DC will likely lead to the acrid smell of disappointment.

---

Generically, you probably want to do something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foP88L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Would not high side switching solve these problems?

Comment: You will now get 9V with switch open and almost 12V with it closed. Still not ideal since the relay will never drop out.

Comment: @JoeyB - You are missing the point entirely. The problem lies with the existence of R1. As long as that is there, the voltage from +12 to the gate of the FET (Vgs) cannot fall below 9 volts, and the FET will always be on.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast correct I realised that, that is why I deleted the comment. Thanks for clarifying though.

Comment: Realized the circuit will not work for my application (in your post), since when Q1 is OFF (Q1 base is 0V), M1 is also OFF therefore RLY1 is OFF. What I needed was when Q1 is OFF M1 is ON and hence RLY1 is ON. Therefore I would need to change M1 to an N channel FET, and utilize LOW-SIDE switching for RLY1.

Comment: I have added the new circuit to my post as edit 2.

Comment: Yes, this should work. An advantage of the transistor (as well as giving you inversion) is that the MOSFET gate is being driven from 12V so you don't need to use a logic-level MOSFET, just one that can withstand (say) +/-20V Vgs to be safe with +12.

Comment: Thanks. I will still accept your answer, since it was your idea that lead to the final solution

Comment: Upvote for "the acrid smell of disappointment."

Comment: Hi Sphero, I have seen that even if the internal control circuitry is not connected, the load is still on. So I added a pull-up resistor in EDIT 3 (R5). Do you see any issues with this? So when the control circuitry is not connected the load (R4) is still off, unlike before.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is worth pointing out that the solution pointed out is still very much incomplete. The reason for this is that the circuit pointed out by Spehro and also the circuit in my Edit 2 is based on the assumption that the NPN BJT is operating in the Cut-off and Saturation regions.

**If you operate the BJT in the active region then Vce can swing between 0V and 12V, which means the FET can always be "ON" if you do not use the correct biasing resistors**

Hence we take the following NPN BJT ZXTN2038FTA, [datasheet here](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXTN2038F.pdf).

Now back to the circuit at hand. We require Vce to be 0V (saturation region), hence Ic (collector current) will be 1.2mA (12V/10kohm).

Therefore from the datasheet we can find the values for beta and Vbe.

[image]

[image]

Hence, we get the following values, assuming we are using the BJT at a temperature of 25:

beta@Ic=1.2mA = 220 (approx.)

Vbe@Ic=1.2mA = 0.6V (approx.)

Therefore,

Ib = 1.2mA/220 = 5.45uA

Rb (base resistance) = (2.8 - 0.6)/5.45uA = 404 kohm

Hence, in order to ensure the BJT remains in the saturated region, Rb must be less than 404 Kohm